Adonis logout with access token
I have implemented register and login with access token in Adonis.
My problem is the logout api call, I cannot figure out how to access token. I tried several approaches:
async logout({ auth }: HttpContextContract) {
  const apiAuth1 = auth.token                      // undefined
  const apiAuth2 = auth.use('api').token           // undefined
  const apiAuth3 = await auth.use('api').getAuth() // auth.use(...).getAuth is not a function

I believe that access-token is accessible since I did the following test in the logout action:
async logout({ auth }: HttpContextContract) {
    const check = await auth.check('api')
    console.log('check: ', check, typeof check)

    const user = auth.user
    console.log('user: ', JSON.stringify(user, null, 2))

    const apiAuth = auth.use('api')
    // Debug the entire apiAuth object
    console.log('apiAuth:', JSON.stringify(apiAuth, null, 2))
}

Which gives me:
check:  true boolean
user:  {
  "id": 27,
  "fullName": "John Doe",
  "email": "johndoe@test.com",
  "createdAt": "2024-06-03T20:12:35.000+00:00",
  "updatedAt": "2024-06-03T20:12:35.000+00:00"
}
apiAuth: {
  "driverName": "access_tokens",
  "authenticationAttempted": true,
  "isAuthenticated": true,
  "user": {
    "id": 27,
    "fullName": "John Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@test.com",
    "createdAt": "2024-06-03T20:12:35.000+00:00",
    "updatedAt": "2024-06-03T20:12:35.000+00:00"
  }
}

Of course the action is protected with AuthMiddleware, which looks like:
import type { HttpContext } from '@adonisjs/core/http'
import type { NextFn } from '@adonisjs/core/types/http'
import type { Authenticators } from '@adonisjs/auth/types'

/**
 * Auth middleware is used authenticate HTTP requests and deny
 * access to unauthenticated users.
 */
export default class AuthMiddleware {
  async handle(
    ctx: HttpContext,
    next: NextFn,
    options: {
      guards?: (keyof Authenticators)[]
    } = {}
  ) {
    const res = await ctx.auth.authenticateUsing(options.guards)
    return next()
  }
}


May be late but this is the solution I guess.
You can get the access token of the user with user.currentAccessToken
You can so get the identifier of it with user.currentAccessToken.identifier
Then, you can delete it from the database with User.accessTokens.delete(user, user.currentAccessToken.identifier)
You can do somethings like that:
async logout({ auth, response }: HttpContext) {
    const user = auth.getUserOrFail()
    const token = user.currentAccessToken.identifier

    if (!token) {
        return response.unauthorized('Invalid token')
    }

     await User.accessTokens.delete(user, token)

     return response.ok('Logged out successfully')
}

